# SUMaC 2018 entrance exam questions

Tags: discussion, contests

The Stanford University Mathematics Camp (SUMaC) 2018 Admission Exam is [online](https://spcsonlineapp.stanford.edu/apply/SUMAC/AdmissionExam.pdf). The rules say, "You are expected to do your own work without the use of any outside source (books, internet search, etc)....Please do not share these problems or your solutions with anyone." At least five of the nine exam questions have been posted to math.stackexchange.com. The application deadline is 14 March, so I would encourage you, if you see a question that looks too clever by half, to check it against the posted exam, and to flag it for moderator attention if it turns out to be from that exam (as I have done for the ones where I have left a comment).

Comment: Related question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11189/is-it-our-responsibility-to-police-for-competition-exam-etc-questions

Comment: Also related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumac

Comment: Related fact: If all PSQs are immediately closed and deleted, we would get rid of 99% of cheating attempts.

Comment: Another related fact: If all humans were to die suddenly, we would get rid of 100% of cheating attempts.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Wrong. Your first statement implies the second, but not the other way around, so the first is **stronger** than the second.

Comment: @user21820 Ok, I was wrong. But am I not achieving the same conclusion , which is getting rid of hundred percent of cheating attempts, by assuming a weaker hypothesis i.e. nobody is on SE? If there are no humans, of course there is nobody on SE, but the other way is not true. I started with a weaker hypothesis, that of SE not  existing, and derived the same statement as that of the related fact. Now I don't know whether this means my statement is "stronger/weaker" or not, but it is correct.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: We cannot police the site for cheaters. Just using a bit of common sense, hardly any of the users on the main site will see this Meta post, and even if they do it is very troublesome to check whether a problem is one of this ongoing contest's problem or not. But it is trivial to determine whether a question is a PSQ or not, and after all PSQs are **already against** the site guidelines. See the tooltip message when you move your mouse over the downvote button. The point is that using SE as intended **automatically** gets rid of most cheaters.

Comment: @user21820 Point taken.

Comment: *"Please do not **share these problems** or your solutions with anyone"* Didn't you just do exactly that? The request sounds like the PDF was not meant to be shared?

Comment: @Adrian, what would you have suggested I do?

Comment: Somehow handling it without publishing it... I would have contacted the people who run the contest first.